# How to code an efficient blacklist filter function in php?

Tags: php, regex, filter

So, I have three arrays like this:

```
 [items] => Array
            ( [0] => Array
                  ( 
                    [id] => someid
                    [title] => sometitle
                    [author] => someauthor
                    ...
                  )
              ...
             )
```

and also a string with comma separated words to blacklist:

```
  $blacklist = "some,words,to,blacklist";
```

Now I need to match these words with (as they can be one of) **id, title**, **author** and show results accordingly.

I was thinking of a function like this:

```
  $pattern = '('.strtr($blacklist, ",", "|").')'; // should return (some|words|etc)

  foreach ($items as $item) {
          if ( !preg_match($pattern,$item['id']) || !preg_match($pattern,$item['title']) || !preg_match($pattern,$item['author']) ) 
               { 
                   // show item
               }
  }
```

and I wonder if this is the most efficient way to filter the arrays or I should use something with **strpos()** or **filter_var** with FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP ...

Note that this function is repeated per 3 arrays. However, each array will not contain more than 50 items.

Comment: You could join the id, title and author into one string (possibly with one divider char). If this really makes a performance difference, I cannot say, though. =)

Comment: The cheating way would be to write stuff to files and use "fgrep -f"

Comment: Is case insensitivity important?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yours isn't bad. I'd typically use `strpos` for something like this...

```
$items = filter($foo['items'], array('some','words','to','blacklist'));

function filter($items, $blacklist) {

    $filtered = array();

    foreach($items as $item) {
        foreach($item as $key => $value) {
            $pass = true;
            foreach($blacklist as $filter) {
                $pass = strpos($value, $filter) === false;
                if(!$pass) break;
            }
            if($pass) $filtered[] = clone($item); 
        }
    }

    return $filtered;
}
```

To add a bit more sophistication, you can tokenize the strings you're checking by whitespace. The code would then become:

```
function filter($items, $blacklist) {

    $filtered = array();

    foreach($items as $item) {
        foreach($item as $key => $value) {
            $pass = true;
            foreach(explode(' ', $value) as $word) {
                $pass = !in_array($word, $blacklist);
                if(!$pass) break;
            }
            if($pass) $filtered[] = clone($item); 
        }
    }

    return $filtered;
}
```